# Massive memory usage with simple rnn network

Tags: python, windows, memory-management, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm trying to learn from a dataset where the longest sequence can be at a length of over 6000 shape=(?, ?, 4), so I pad them like this:

```
for data in y_data:
        count = max_len - len(data)
        for i in range(count):
            data.append(np.zeros(4))
```

My model looks like this:

```
def get_net(sequence_length):
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, length, 4])
    net = tflearn.lstm(net, n_units=128, dropout=0.8)
    net =  tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='linear')
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer="adam", loss='mean_square')
    return tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
```

When I try to learn from this data the computation needs a long time. After it has filled around 3Gb of memory it starts to build the model. After an even longer time, at around 10Gb there happen strange jumps and the model can start computation.

I really don't think that this is supposed to happen. Have I made a mistake?

Os: Windows 10
Tensorflow: 1.1.0
Python: 3.5.0

**EDIT**

---

```
# global train- and test data
x_data = []
y_data = []
max_len = 0

# The csv files are formatted like this: "%i,%i,%i,%i;%f,%f"
for csv_file in files[:10]: 

    # Open csv-files
    with open(os.path.join(data_dir, csv_file), 'r') as f:
        # local train- and test data
        csv_x_data = []
        csv_y_data = []
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            while True:
                data = line.split(';')
                # append each rows data to the local train- and test data 
                csv_x_data.append([int(x) for x in data[0].split(',')])
                csv_y_data.append([float(x) for x in data[1].split(',')])
                line = f.readline()
                if not line:
                    break

        # Appending values to the  
        x_data.append(csv_x_data)
        y_data.append(csv_y_data)

        # Keep track of max_length for padding
        csv_len = len(csv_x_data)
        if csv_len > max_len:
            max_len = csv_len

# Padding the sequences
for data in x_data:
    count = max_len - len(data)
    for i in range(count):
        data.append(np.zeros(4))

print("data loaded")

# Not sure if I have to format the labels in the same way as the training data
# for data in y_data:
#     count = max_len - len(data)
#     for i in range(count):
#         data.append(np.zeros(4))

model = get_net(max_len)
print("model loaded")

x_data = np.array(x_data)
y_data = np.array(y_data)
model.fit(x_data, y_data, validation_set=0.1, batch_size=5) # batch_size for testing proposes so small
```

I initially started out with 500 files, but I had to realise, that the memory problem is so severe, that even 10 files are too much

[Example csv-files](https://puu.sh/wFj5H/33e3facb42.zip)

Comment: Can you provide an example in how you call the method? I.e. a minimal working example.

Comment: @JonasAdler Done. I'll upload a small dataset immediately